# Triangle pattern printing in Python

Tags: python

Write  a  program  that  prompts  the  user  to  enter  the  maximum  value  of  range  and display the values in the triangle format and use any notation for the white space to make a complete triangle.Example:Enter the maximum range: 37
[image]

This is the solution I came up with. But the space printed is incorrect. Can anyone help?

```
max = 37
max2 = max

no_of_lines = 0
subtractor = 1
while max>=1:
    no_of_lines+=1
    max = max-subtractor
    subtractor +=1

counter = 1
for i in range(no_of_lines):
    print((no_of_lines-i)*" " + (no_of_lines-i-1)*" ", end="")

    # the next loop is to create the string of numbers in a line
    s = ""
    for k in range(i+1):
        if(counter>max2):
            s = " "+"*"+s
        else:
            s = " "+str(counter)+s
        counter+=1
    print(s)
```

Comment: You are not taking into account the difference between 1-digit numbers and 2-digit numbers.  The easy way to handle that is by using `"%2d"%counter` instead of `str(counter)`.  You'll also need to use `" *"` instead of `"*"`, and change the lead-in spacing.

Comment: Check out the `str.rjust` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the tweaks needed to make your code work.  BTW, the advice to look at the `rjust` function is good advice.

```
max = 37
max2 = max

no_of_lines = 0
subtractor = 1
while max>=1:
    no_of_lines+=1
    max = max-subtractor
    subtractor +=1

counter = 1
for i in range(no_of_lines):
    print((no_of_lines-i)*" " + (no_of_lines-i-1)*"  ", end="")

    # the next loop is to create the string of numbers in a line
    s = ""
    for k in range(i+1):
        if(counter>max2):
            s = " "+" *"+s
        else:
            s = " "+"%2d"%counter+s
        counter+=1
    print(s)
```

Output:

```
                           1
                        3  2
                     6  5  4
                 10  9  8  7
              15 14 13 12 11
           21 20 19 18 17 16
        28 27 26 25 24 23 22
     36 35 34 33 32 31 30 29
   *  *  *  *  *  *  *  * 37
```

Comment: Apart from a couple of unnecessary leading spaces on each output line, this works well providing the input value (37 in this case) is a 2-digit number.

Comment: Yes, in this case I tried to use their code with a minimum of changes rather than redesign.  For example, there's probably a numerical method to determine the number of rows given N, instead of doing it iteratively.

Answer (score 2):

Ensuring proper alignment for any value of N (spuriously named *max* in OP's original code) is awkward. The flawed code in the question implies that N will always be a 2-digit value but that may not necessarily be the case.

This approach, albeit more complex, handles multi-digit values for N:

```
N = 37
v = i = 1
t = []

while v <= N:
    t.append([])
    for _ in range(i):
        t[-1].append(v)
        if (v := v + 1) > N:
            break
    i += 1

m = 1 if N == 1 else len(t[-2])+1
w = len(str(N))

for i, _t in enumerate(t, 1):
    line = [f'{v:>{w}}' for v in _t]
    if (pad := m - len(line)) > 0:
        fill = '*' if i == len(t) else ' '
        line += [f'{fill:>{w}}' for _ in range(pad)]
    print(' '.join(reversed(line)))
```

**Output:**

```
                         1
                      3  2
                   6  5  4
               10  9  8  7
            15 14 13 12 11
         21 20 19 18 17 16
      28 27 26 25 24 23 22
   36 35 34 33 32 31 30 29
 *  *  *  *  *  *  *  * 37
```